# How to return multiple values if a row contains a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I want to look up a number in column A and return column B and C if it is there. So, on another worksheet I'd input FG30827110 and have four items returned (Each item in column B and C returned).

[image]

Comment: Advanced Filter?

Comment: Maybe.  Let me add clarity.  I'll need to know that if I have to build 4 pcs of the FG#, I will need 8 pcs of the PC00065 (because it is 2 per).  But another set of cells might call out 3 pcs per and I'd need 12 total PC00065.  In the end, I need to know total quantity of column B with varying quantities of column A.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It sounds like the formula for column b is something like (if "a2=x" then "y") and column c is similarly setup. I would add another column for "number of pc's" and modify column c to multiply its output by that new column. Basically A2=FG30827110 --> B2=PC00065 --> C2(# of PCs)=2 --> D2=B2*C2 which would output 4.

Comment: @Nick Scolaro - please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1373200/edit) instead of using comments to add information

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula to pull the component item

```
=INDEX(Table1[parent item no],MATCH(A1,Table1[child item no],0))
```

(this must be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

Then use `SUMIFS` to get the quantity

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[pts per],Table1[parent item no],A1,Table1[child item no],b1)*(qty needed)
```